# Nested for loop to iterate through struct containing array elements is not working in golang

Tags: go

Trying to iterate through item list but getting below error :

```
./prog.go:25:39: invalid operation: checkItems[i] (type struct { items string; size []string; color []string } does not support indexing)
./prog.go:28:69: invalid operation: checkItems[i] (type struct { items string; size []string; color []string } does not support indexing)
```

Here is the code :
https://play.golang.org/p/zdCe-BC2t_D

Comment: Please post the code in the question body instead of a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line `for i, checkItems := range checkItems`, you redefine `checkItems` which overwrite the original `checkItems`, so now `checkItems` only indicates one item of original `checkItems` whose type should be `struct`, not the list any more.

The solution is rename the second `checkItems` into another one like `checkItem`

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    checkItems := []struct {
        items string
        size  []string
        color []string
    }{
        {
            items: "Shirt",
            size:  []string{"XL", "L", "S", "XS"},
            color: []string{"Brown", "Black", "White"},
        },
        {
            items: "Shoes",
            size:  []string{"10", "8"},
            color: []string{"White", "Brown"},
        },
    }
    for i, checkItem := range checkItems {
        for j, _ := range checkItem.size {

            fmt.Println("Hello, playground", i, "checkitems", checkItem)
            fmt.Println("Hello, playground", j, "checkitems size", checkItems[i].size[j])
        }

    }
}
```